# mysql fill missing values with 0

Tags: mysql, missing-data

I have a mysql query that sometimes results in missing values. For my dashboard I'd like to fill those values, but would prefer to avoid build dummy tables if I can.

query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Comms_Timestamp) as call_count,DAYOFWEEK(Comms_Timestamp) as bucket 
FROM tblTest GROUP BY bucket;
```

results in

```
+------------+--------+
| call_count | bucket |
+------------+--------+
|          4 |      1 |
|          7 |      2 |
|          7 |      3 |
|          1 |      5 |
|          6 |      6 |
|          1 |      7 |
+------------+--------+
```

In the above example you can see bucket 4 is missing. I consider the method where the join is to a select union array, however since both fields are aggregates, I'm not sure how to go about it.

test data is

```
+---------------------+
| Comms_Timestamp     |
+---------------------+
| 2018-12-24 06:04:05 |
| 2018-12-24 12:18:39 |
| 2018-12-21 04:24:31 |
| 2018-12-21 08:32:44 |
| 2018-12-30 01:41:06 |
| 2018-12-30 01:53:00 |
| 2018-12-30 01:53:39 |
| 2018-12-30 02:00:01 |
| 2018-12-17 15:55:03 |
| 2018-12-17 16:04:12 |
| 2018-12-17 16:05:41 |
| 2018-12-17 16:07:43 |
| 2018-12-17 16:10:25 |
| 2018-12-18 14:03:22 |
| 2018-12-18 14:03:29 |
| 2018-12-18 14:10:19 |
| 2018-12-18 14:10:29 |
| 2018-12-18 14:10:31 |
| 2018-12-18 14:10:47 |
| 2018-12-18 14:10:55 |
| 2018-12-20 08:21:07 |
| 2018-12-28 11:03:59 |
| 2018-12-28 12:06:40 |
| 2018-12-28 12:15:01 |
| 2018-12-28 14:29:24 |
| 2019-01-05 13:33:43 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Can u post few more things like the structure of the two tables with some data in it?
This much info is inadequate to suggest properly.

Comment: this might help you [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185079/get-previous-12-month-data-and-if-not-exist-then-add-zero-in-mysql)

Comment: @RaviGaudani I'm specifically trying to avoid building empty tables..

Comment: @BhushanShinde done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mysql and don't have access to the `seq_` option, here is an alternative way:

```
SELECT A.x AS bucket, IF(ISNULL(COUNT(t2.Comms_Timestamp)), 0, COUNT(t2.Comms_Timestamp)) AS call_count FROM
(select 1 x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7) AS A
LEFT JOIN tblTest AS t2 ON DAYOFWEEK(t2.Comms_Timestamp) = A.x
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY bucket;
```

It may not be the prettiest option but will do what you need.

Here is a db fiddel link: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ad3bce336deecb07f4276c6c1c9d6fd)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB there is their [Sequence Storage Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/)

There is no create needed for this table, however the maximum value must be known.

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version()                                   |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~stretch-log |
> ```

> ```
> create table bob (a int)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into bob values (4),(2)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from seq_1_to_5
> ```
>
> ```
> | seq |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> |   2 |
> |   3 |
> |   4 |
> |   5 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT s.seq, bob.a
> FROM seq_1_to_5 s 
> LEFT JOIN bob 
>   ON bob.a = s.seq
> ORDER BY s.seq
> ```
>
> ```
> seq |    a
> --: | ---:
>   1 | null
>   2 |    2
>   3 | null
>   4 |    4
>   5 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=eda26199f6da744d530926fd1cdd3008)*

Comment: unfortunately I'm running mysql for this one

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL() function in MYSQL:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(C.Comms_Timestamp),0) as call_count,IFNULL(DAYOFWEEK(C.Comms_Timestamp),0) as bucket 
FROM tblCommunication as C LEFT JOIN tblCareTeam as CT on C.id_Case = CT.id_Case 
GROUP BY CT.id_Site,bucket 
HAVING CT.id_Site=8;
```

Comment: Sorry that defintly doesn't do anything